# Why I can't load scripts with specific filenames with `load`?

Tags: ruby, load, filenames

Yesterday I discovered, that I can't reload my script `rss.rb` using `load`. It only do something unknown for me for several seconds, returns `true` and doesn't execute script. But It can be loaded (once) with no problems using `require_relative`. I had to rename script file, to use it as I wanted.
**So why `require_relative` works, but `load` doesn't? And how to know, which filenames can't be loaded with `load`?**
I'm using *ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]*

UPD:

```
C:> type 1.rb
p load 'rss.rb'
p load '2.rb'

C:> type rss.rb
p 'rss.rb loaded'

C:> type 2.rb
p '2.rb loaded'

C:> ruby 1.rb
true
"2.rb loaded"
true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading the rss.rb from the standard library. `load` goes through the `$LOAD_PATH` first and only if the file is not found there, looks for the file in the current directory.

You can make it look only in the current directory by doing `load "./rss.rb"`.

The reason it works with `require_relative` is that `require_relative` never looks at the `$LOAD_PATH`.

When using `load` you should keep in mind that `load`, unlike `require_relative` will look for the file in the current directory, not in the directory where the script is. So whether or not it finds the file depends on which directory you're in when invoking the script. (Of course the same was true for loading local files using `require` in previous ruby versions).